# My program, that uses the Java MSN Messenger library, is in error

Tags: android

I want to develop a program using the Java MSN Messenger library ([JML](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/java-jml)). I can not solve a problem where the following exeception is thrown.

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(312): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-21

**ERROR/AndroidRuntime(312):     java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(312):     at net.sf.jml.protocol.incoming.IncomingUSR$1.getLoginTicket(IncomingUSR.java:198)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(312):     at net.sf.jml.protocol.incoming.IncomingUSR$1.run(IncomingUSR.java:247)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(312):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(312):     at net.sf.jml.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:58)
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(312):
                     ... 2 more**
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution, i hope this can help to someone.

You must to recompile jml with a little change in net.sf.jml.util.StringUtils.java

1º Download the code of jml here:

```
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-jml/files/java-jml/jml-1.0b4/
```

2º And then apply this patch

```
 http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2910514&group_id=118829&atid=682291
```

(i recomend download the code with a svn program and then aply the patch with tolstoi or other svn program )

When you have the code parched, create a .jar (right click in the project / export ) and then add this .jar to your msn project.

(solution based in : http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-jml/forums/forum/405891/topic/4093769 )

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to use [Java MSN Messenger library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-jml/). This library was created for J2SE/J2EE and can not be used on Android.

As you can see net.sf.jml.util.StringUtils is referencing sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction which is not available on Android.

Comment: what library can use for Android?

Comment: i want to use library for android